# How to apply defined function on other column than defined

Tags: pandas

I have a function that returns the BMI from a given dataframe with columns 'Weight' and 'Height'
Here is the function:

```py
def BMI(dataframe):
    return dataframe['Weight'] / (dataframe['Height']**2)
```

I added new column 'Height In Meters' to the dataframe 'data' with:

```py
data['Height In Meters'] = data['Height']/100
```

What i would like to do next, is to apply the **original** function on the dataframe 'data',
but instead of using the column 'Height', the calculation would be by using the new column 'Height In Meters'.

the result should be a new column called 'BMI' in the dataframe 'data', that shows for each row the calculation using 'Height In Meters'.

I tried:

```py
data['BMI'] = data[['Weight','Height In Meters']].apply(BMI,axis=1)
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `data['BMI'] = dataframe['Weight']  / dataframe['Height In Meters'] ** 2` should work, you don't need a function

Comment: If you really want to use a function, you can pass the column name as a parameter : `def BMI(dataframe, height_col): ... / (dataframe[height_col]**2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass the column names as arguments:

```
def BMI(dataframe, col1, col2):
    return dataframe[col1] / (dataframe[col2]**2)

a = data.apply(BMI, args=('Weight', 'Height'), axis=1)

data['Height In Meters'] = data['Height']/100

b = data.apply(BMI, args=('Weight', 'Height In Meters'), axis=1)
```